# Unable to create emulators with older versions although the Api are fully installed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm trying to create an emulator with KitKat and IceCreamSandwich in android studio to test my program with. I have downloaded all required Apis in SDK Manager:

[image]
[image]

But I'm not able to choose any version other that 6 when creating or editing an emulator:

[image]
[image]

What is the problem?

Comment: You have the SDKs installed, doesn't mean you have the system images installed. Try using the standalone sdk manager to see what all is installed.

Comment: @Ali I have used the standalone sdk manager and installed system images too. I uploaded this image only to let you know that api are installed.

Comment: That's a tough one, I would recommend to cut your losses and use [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/features/) for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the checked item in below image. You can find this in Android SDK manager and then try to run emulator.

[image]